# Cipher suite needed for downloading from windows store

Tags: windows-10-v1909

Does anyone know which Cipher Suite needs to be enabled on a Win10 machine to download packages from the Windows store. I need to configure my device with a subset of ciphers and when I do it fails with error 0x80240438.

I used fiddler and i saw the connection from svchost being closed.

Note that if I disable the custom cipher list, I don't have a problem.

Here is the cypher list I have configured:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P256
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
```

Comment: The required ciphers to download something on the Windows Store are already installed.  In fact the cryptography library used by Windows cannot actually be uninstalled.

Comment: Yeah, i know the OS supports it, I just need to know which one i need to add to the list above.

Comment: **You didn't originally provide that list.**

Comment: I don't understand your test results.  [This](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.microsoft.com&s=2600%3a1406%3a1400%3a6aa%3a0%3a0%3a0%3a356e&hideResults=on&ignoreMismatch=on) indicates that microsoft.com supports all those ciphers.  You could try throwing one of the weaker TLS 1.2/TLS 1.1 ciphers into your list to see if that makes a difference.  To my knowledge the Microsoft Store application itself uses Legacy Edge to display the web content.  The next first of the web content control is out but Microsoft Store won't get that update until the next refresh (more than likely)

Comment: The reason Microsoft.com was used because the application is obviously communicating with that host.  The cipher being used would be determine by the server not the application (client) in a case like this.

Comment: In wireshark I just see the connection being reset

Comment: So have you added one of the weaker ciphers to see if that resolves the problem?

Comment: Not yet. I'll have to try later...